# Chaco and wxpython integration?

Tags: wxpython, chaco, anaconda

Is there an integration interface between wxpython and Chaco?

Documentation seems sparse, the Anaconda package had examples for VTK and QT but not WX.

This was the closest documentation I found, but it's outdated. 
http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/how_do_i.html
The enable package does not have wx_backend anymore. Tried switching to enable.wx.base_window but got NotImplementedError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willy, thanks for pointing out that our WX example is broken: the place to import the Window should be:

```
from enable.api import Window
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set environ variable at the beggining of the script

```
import os
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT']='wx'
```